# How do I build an app for iOS and Android in the most efficient, DRY way?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, cross-platform

*Disclaimer before anyone will mark this as "opinion-based": I'm not looking for opinions but resources.*

I've been planning an app that I'm going to build in Flutter. I'm experienced in several programming languages but I'm a beginner in Flutter, which is quite unique when it comes to its underlying purposes (cross-platform application).

I'm wondering how I handle this "one codebase, two platforms" situation, and I can't for my life find resources on:

1. General recommended approaches from the Flutter team
2. Separation of Material and Cupertino widgets, while persisting reusability of the widgets. (I don't want to go across the whole app and spread IF-ELSE blocks everywhere I need iOS- or Android-specific UI elements.)
3. How do I organize my platform-specific code? E.g. the default Flutter app includes `android` and `ios` folders, and I'm assuming they are for some sort of separation of concerns. I cannot find information on how this separation is actually applied.

I guess my question is not *"Can you show me how to do it?"* but rather **"Can you point me toward resources (blogs, videos, docs, etc.) that could help me understand how I should use Flutter to keep my code DRY, efficient, and scalable when I build an iOS/Android app?"**.

All I can find are articles like **[this one](https://medium.com/flutter/do-flutter-apps-dream-of-platform-aware-widgets-7d7ed7b4624d)** from 2018 - and this seems early-stage and hacky.

**--- UPDATE: ---**

I found **[documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/platform-adaptations#ui-components)** from Flutter that touches upon this subject. Essentially, there are some "adaptive" control widgets ready to use, but other than that it's an IF-ELSE game as shown in the code examples in the docs.

Comment: I haven't tried it but do you know [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets)?

Comment: @PeterKoltai Thanks, I'll look into it because generally, libraries are there to solve or facilitate common problems, and what I'm asking about is exactly that. The downside is that a library is a "one man's point of view" and what I'd love to see is some official guidelines or in-depth resources. For a framework that is supposed to work cross-platform, I'm just surprised not much can be found online on the actual cross-platform, real-life development.

Comment: I agree. This seems to be a maintained library with many contributors, recent updates. Might worth a shot.

Comment: you can look for an application development technology that targets both runtimes. Maybe do some research into react native, web applications and PWAs, Flutter, etc.